# Is wine banned or is alcohol banned? Can we use products, such as deodorant, which contain alcohol?

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol

Any addictive substance is banned in Islam. It includes smoking, drinking, etc.

Now, my question is: **is wine banned or is alcohol banned?**

I am asking this as many Muslims say not to use deodorants which contain alcohol, or any daily usage which contain minimal traces of alcohol.

So can we use (in any form/any way) any non-addictive thing which contain minimal traces of alcohol?

Answer (score 2):

**Is wine banned or is alcohol banned?**

All intoxicants are haram for consumption. The wines and alcohols that cause intoxication are totally forbidden.

> 'A'isha reported that Allaah's Messenger (sallAllaahu alayhi wa
>   sallam) was asked about it, whereupon he said that everything that
>   causes intoxication is forbidden.
>
> Ibn 'Umar reported Allaah's Messenger (sallAllaahu alayhi wa sallam)
>   as saying: Every intoxicant is Khamr and every intoxicant is
>   forbidden. He who drinks wine in this world and dies while he is
>   addicted to it, not having repented, will not be given a drink in the
>   Hereafter.
>
> Abu Musa reported: Allaah's Prophet (sallAllaahu alayhi wa sallam)
>   sent me and Mu'adh b. Jabal to Yemen. I said: Allaah's Messenger,
>   there is prepared in our land a wine out of barley which is known as
>   Mizr (beer of our times) and a wine from honey which is known as Bit,
>   (are these also forbidden? ), whereupon he said: **Every intoxicant is
>   forbidden.**
>
> [Sahih Muslim](http://www.sahihmuslim.com/sps/smm/sahihmuslim.cfm?scn=dspchaptersfull&BookID=23&ChapterID=844)

---

**Can we use products, such as deodorant, which contain alcohol?**

The prohibition on consumption of intoxicants doesn't mean that using (without drinking/consuming) products that contain alchol (which is an intoxicant) is haram. The prohibition applies to drinking/consuming alchol not using deodorant or other products that contain some alchol. Scholars at IslamQA.info says:

> We need to talk at length about the issue of perfumes that are said to
>   contain cologne or alcohol. If the percentage of alcohol is very
>   little, we say that it does not matter, and a person may use them
>   without any concern, such as **if the alcohol content is 5% or less.**
>   This does not matter.
>
> If the percentage of alcohol is very high, so that you can detect it,
>   then it is better not to use it except where it is necessary, such as
>   for sterilizing wounds and the like.
>
> In cases where it is not necessary, it is better not to use it, but **we
>   do not say that it is haram.** The most we can say is that this high
>   alcohol content is an intoxicant, and no doubt consuming intoxicants
>   is haram according to the texts of Islam and the consensus of the
>   scholars, but is using it in ways other than drinking it permissible?
>   **This is open to speculation, but to be on the safe side we should not
>   use it.**
>
> [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/1365)

Answer (score 0):

**Is wine banned or is alcohol banned?**

An ayat from the Holy Quran:

> They ask you about wine and gambling. Say, "In them is great sin and
>   [yet, some] benefit for people. But their sin is greater than their
>   benefit." And they ask you what they should spend. Say, "The excess
>   [beyond needs]." Thus Allah makes clear to you the verses [of
>   revelation] that you might give thought.
>   Al Bakarah - Ayat 219

A hadith:

> “The Prophet (p.b.u.h.) said: If a large amount of anything causes
>   intoxication, a small amount of it is prohibited.” (Sunan Abi Dawud,
>   Drinks, 3681)

Source: http://www.islamandquran.org/fatwas/is-non-alcoholic-beer-permissible.html

**So can we use (in any form/any way) any non-addictive thing which contain minimal traces of alcohol?**

> Ethyl alcohol is actually the intoxicating substance in alcoholic
>   drinks. However, it is already included in many foods such as bread,
>   orange peel, ready-sold dough; and our body needs it to a certain
>   extent. In Qur’an Al-Karim, the word  ‘alcohol’ is not mentioned.  **The
>   Glorified Allah forbids consuming intoxicants.** However, drinks and
>   other foods do not intoxicate as long as the ratio of alcohol within
>   them reach a certain amount. If a substance includes sugar or starch,
>   ethyl alcohol emerges in it, although you do not interfere. If you do
>   interfere and add more than a certain amount of alcohol to drinks,
>   they become intoxicant and forbidden.
>
> As a result, those drugs do not intoxicate and therefore are not
>   forbidden.

Source:
http://www.islamandquran.org/fatwas/what-is-the-ruling-on-taking-drugs-that-include-alcohol.html

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. I stringly recommed you to take your time to elarn more about our site and model by taking our 2 min. [tour] and checking our [help].